# I am getting a not a statement error

Tags: java

I need help figuring out what I am doing wrong. Here is my coding so far. 
I am trying to plot coordinates on a circle. I get a not a statement error.

```
public class MathClass
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

    double y1;
    double y2;
    System.out.println("Points on a Circle of Radius 1.0");
    System.out.printf ( "%6s" , "x1", "y1", "x1" , "y2");
    System.out.println ("----------------------------------");
    for (double x1 = 1.00; x1> -1.10; x1 + -0.10)
    {
        double x1sq= Math.pow(x1,2);
        double r = 1;
        double y1sq = r- x1sq;
        y1= Math.sqrt(y1sq);
        System.out.printf( "%.2f", x1, "   ", y1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full error.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is on line 10 of the code you posted. The issue is that `x1 + -0.10` is an expression, not a statement (hence the "not a statement" error that you're getting). You want `x1 += -0.10` instead. Or, to be more clear about it, use `-=` instead of adding a negative, so the whole loop condition looks like this:

```
for (double x1 = 1.00; x1 > -1.10; x1 -= 0.10)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `for` loop. You can rewrite it like this:

```
for (double x1 = 1.00; x1> -1.10; x1 -= 0.10)
```

Answer (score 0):

x1 + -0.10  is your problem, did you want x1 += -0.10

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is wrong

use  `x1 -=0.10`

```
  for (double x1 = 1.00; x1> -1.10; x1 -=0.10)
    {
        double x1sq= Math.pow(x1,2);
        double r = 1;
        double y1sq = r- x1sq;
        y1= Math.sqrt(y1sq);
        System.out.printf( "%.2f", x1, "   ", y1);

    }
```